# When using lubridate::day() to extract day, how to set that day will be defined as starting at a time rather than midnight?

Tags: r, time, lubridate

How can I define days to circle from 5am to 5am rather than 0am to 0am, using lubridate (or otherwise)?

### My Data

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df <- structure(list(created_at = structure(c(1594758763, 1594804279, 
1594709405, 1594760043, 1594702619, 1594802165, 1594654865, 1594767077, 
1594750851, 1594736216), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), mood = 1:10), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

df

## # A tibble: 10 x 2
##    created_at           mood
##    <dttm>              <int>
##  1 2020-07-14 20:32:43     1
##  2 2020-07-15 09:11:19     2
##  3 2020-07-14 06:50:05     3
##  4 2020-07-14 20:54:03     4
##  5 2020-07-14 04:56:59     5
##  6 2020-07-15 08:36:05     6
##  7 2020-07-13 15:41:05     7
##  8 2020-07-14 22:51:17     8
##  9 2020-07-14 18:20:51     9
## 10 2020-07-14 14:16:56    10
```

**Let's say that I want to see how mood changes as a function of day.**

First, it's easier for me to define "day" as the day in the month (July in this case). Therefore, it's useful to use `day()` to extract the day.

```r
df %>% mutate(day_in_july = day(created_at))

## # A tibble: 10 x 3
##    created_at           mood day_in_july
##    <dttm>              <int>       <int>
##  1 2020-07-14 20:32:43     1          14
##  2 2020-07-15 09:11:19     2          15
##  3 2020-07-14 06:50:05     3          14
##  4 2020-07-14 20:54:03     4          14
##  5 2020-07-14 04:56:59     5          14
##  6 2020-07-15 08:36:05     6          15
##  7 2020-07-13 15:41:05     7          13
##  8 2020-07-14 22:51:17     8          14
##  9 2020-07-14 18:20:51     9          14
## 10 2020-07-14 14:16:56    10          14
```

Now, let's say that for my purpose, it makes more sense to define "day" as starting at 5AM rather than midnight. How could I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just work out the `day` after subtracting 5 hours. That way a time of, say 4am, one day will be counted as belonging to the previous day.

```
df %>% mutate(day_in_july = day(created_at - hours(5)))
#> # A tibble: 10 x 3
#>    created_at           mood day_in_july
#>    <dttm>              <int>       <int>
#>  1 2020-07-14 20:32:43     1          14
#>  2 2020-07-15 09:11:19     2          15
#>  3 2020-07-14 06:50:05     3          14
#>  4 2020-07-14 20:54:03     4          14
#>  5 2020-07-14 04:56:59     5          13
#>  6 2020-07-15 08:36:05     6          15
#>  7 2020-07-13 15:41:05     7          13
#>  8 2020-07-14 22:51:17     8          14
#>  9 2020-07-14 18:20:51     9          14
#> 10 2020-07-14 14:16:56    10          14
```